# SQL IF Statement With dates

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2013, iif

So I can not seem to enter date or `IIF` Statement without syntax errors!

```
SELECT iif ([hire_date] = <'#2000-01-01#','Old Gaurd')
From L_employees
```

I need to write a `IIF` statement that checks if `[Hire_Date]` is before the year *2000* then replace it with *OLD PROS*, otherwise *Young GUNS*.

Comment: Can edit your question to make it more readable and less desperate?

Comment: Face Palm, lol when Someone needs Help they ARE Desperate. An Yes I can Edit The Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logical operator is invalid and you have not supplied `iif` with the result you want to show in case `[expression ]`evaluates to false:

```
select iif([hire_date] <= #2000-01-01#, 'Old Gaurd', 'Young')
from L_employees
```

Comment: @Star314: You're welcome, don't forget to mark as answered. Also edit your question to make it look decent and readable for people .

Comment: Ok I will mark the Question Answered. How would I make my POST look better. I can not add Pictures. And I gave my code, plus problem???? I'm not upset just trying to improve?

Comment: @Star314: You can also format your code, include your syntax error description and  write problem elaboration without mistakes – that will make your issue easier to solve.

Comment: See I love Details... Thank you for elaborating... I'm still new & need to learn my way around.